# How to find derivative $f'(t)$ using the integral from $0$ to $t^2$ of $\sin(x^4)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If the $t^2$ was just $t$, I know the derivative is $\sin(t^4)$. How does having an upper limit of $t^2$ change $\sin(x^4)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need the chain rule to help. See this
$$\left(\int_a^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt = \right)'= f\circ g(x)g'(x)$$

Comment: Is this saying that the derivative is g(x) * g'(x)? I have done chain rule for computing derivatives but not when integrals are involved. Thanks

Comment: This is the chain rule along with the fundamental theorem of calculus (derivative of integral version)